# execute callback after all iframes finish loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Trying out a small jquery plugin to make the user experience of html input file upload control consistent across browsers. Its basically a form which has an html input control which is nested in a hidden iframe.

The plugin exposes events like `beforeUpload`, `afterUpload` etc, and I am able to wire these correctly.

Here is a sample of how I'd invoke the `afterUpload` event.

```
$.fn.createUpload = function(config){
    //stuff

    $(myUploadIframe).load(function(){
        var doc = this.contentWindow.document;
        var txt = $(doc).text();

        //parse txt to get json results
        var result = frameWorkParser(txt);

        if(result.uploadSuccess){
            if(config.afterUpload){
                config.afterUpload(sender, result);
            }
        }
    });

    //other stuff
};
```

Here is how I'd consume the plugin:

```
var config = {
    afterUpload: function(el, data){
        //set some hidden field
    },
    //other options
};
$('#btnSelectFile').createUpload(config);
```

If I've somehow invoked nested form (i.e inside the iframe) submit method, the iframe loads and I am able to successfully call the `afterUpload` event.

But here is where things get trickier. I am trying to execute some logic after all uploads are completed.

```
$.doUploads = function (callback) {
    $('iframe').each(function () {
        if (this.id.indexOf('_uploadContainer') > -1) {
            var doc = this.contentWindow.document;
            doc.forms[0].submit();
        }
    });
    callback();
};
```

Here I am iterating all the plugin-created iframes (created for uploading) and invoking the nested form submit method. But this call doesn't wait for the consequent iframe `onload` event to complete, and the `callback` executes.

I want the callback to execute post the `afterUpload` event of my plugin. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Set some int variable(say `totaliframeloaded=0;`) which gets incremented on every iframe load. also give a call to callback function on every iframe load.

In callback check, whether that int variable has length equal to `$('iframe').length`. This condition will be getting matched when all the iframes gets loaded.

```
if(`totaliframeloaded==$('iframe').length){//all iframes are loaded
//callback coad
}else{
//do nothing/return
}
```